# Excel VBA Count rows for a certain criteria in closed workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel VBA code to pull data from a closed workbook.
The macro works and pulls the data, but my data set has data for five different accounts consolidated into one file. The only way I can pull the data for that one specific account is if I put the correct number of rows of data for that specific account but I would have to count it from my data set which it beats the purpose from automating it.

I want to put a dynamic count function vba code in the following code below.

Lets say I want to pull all the row data for account "P 87848".

```
Const NumRows& = 250
```

What would be the best way to insert or implement a count function in the Const NumRow&

```
Sub GetDataDemo()

    Dim FilePath$, Row&, Column&, Address$
    Dim path As String


     'change constants & FilePath below to suit
     '***************************************
    Const FileName$ = "DNAV.xlsx"
    Const SheetName$ = "DNAV"
    Const NumRows& = 250
    Const NumColumns& = 15
    path = "C:\Documents\Marenco\VBA\"
     '***************************************

    DoEvents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Dir(FilePath & FileName) = Empty Then
        MsgBox "The file " & FileName & " was not found", , "File Doesn't Exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Row = 1 To NumRows
        For Column = 1 To NumColumns
            Address = Cells(Row, Column).Address
            Cells(Row, Column) = GetData(FilePath, FileName, SheetName, Address)
            Columns.AutoFit
        Next Column
    Next Row
    ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False
End Sub


Private Function GetData(path, File, Sheet, Address)
    Dim Data$
    Data = "'" & path & "[" & File & "]" & Sheet & "'!" & _
    Range(Address).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
    GetData = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Data)
End Function
```

My Source Data. Account Number is in Column A, and it has 5 different account starting with P 15001. Each account has its own template. In this case I want to pull the data for account P 15001 only. The Column are constant, but the rows changes.

### Account Number Security ID Quantity Cost Local Market Price Market Value Local

```
P 15001 AUD 276,250.00  276,250.00  1.00    276,250.00 
P 15001 B5790J3 4,000,000.00    4,086,200.00    110.60  4,424,080.00 
P 15001 B3XF8Z3 5,000,000.00    5,239,900.00    109.98  5,498,750.00 
P 15001 B50VKT6 5,000,000.00    5,134,250.00    103.37  5,168,300.00 
P 15001 CCTAUD  615,000.00  615,000.00  0.96    615,000.00 
P 15001 B3XQ210 6,900,000.00    7,090,440.00    101.82  7,025,511.00 
P 15001 B55HXF6 4,300,000.00    4,522,844.40    105.50  4,536,543.00 
P 15001 B4PM5Y7 2,900,000.00    3,145,730.42    112.29  3,256,381.00 
P 15001 CCTCAD  2,530,000.00    2,530,000.00    0.99    2,530,000.00 
P 15001 EUR 82,921.26   82,921.26   1.00    82,921.26 
P 15001 B5VVFK1 5,600,000.00    5,992,648.00    106.60  5,969,415.20 
P 15001 B10S9K3 7,270,000.00    8,794,985.99    124.58  9,056,960.88 
P 15001 B4XF7K8 10,530,000.00   12,079,614.58   118.06  12,431,696.94 
P 15001 B5V3C06 14,500,000.00   14,511,620.00   100.44  14,564,467.00 
P 15001 B54VTS4 35,150,000.00   35,922,019.50   104.24  36,640,535.75 
P 15001 B6YXBD6 3,580,000.00    3,719,341.36    109.04  3,903,753.72 
P 15001 B40Z1F4 2,530,000.00    2,814,675.60    111.38  2,817,797.62 
P 15001 B63GF45 6,150,000.00    7,170,378.00    117.56  7,229,884.65 
P 15001 B04FJB4 34,850,000.00   38,186,084.50   108.91  37,956,668.40 
P 15001 B45JHF3 9,200,000.00    9,935,736.49    105.81  9,734,547.60 
P 15001 B28VPL4 970,000.00  1,113,787.27    114.05  1,106,277.14
```

Comment: How is the source data set generated? Is that something you can control? How to tell which area belongs to which account?

Comment: The source data is generated by a system and the reports are sent vial email and is automatically saved to a drive. The file consolidates 5 accounts in them. The source data has 33 Columns, the Rows changes on a daily basis depending on numbers of positions. The account numbers are in Column A, and account 1 can have more than 200 rows of data.

Comment: So the source is not something you can control. Can you give an illustration on the account -> data_area relationship? It's hard to get hint from your code.

Comment: The source I can control, the system generates the files.

Comment: Passerby I posted  a sample of the source data. So in this instance all the accounts will be posted in Column A, so in the code "Const NumRows& = 250 " I want a "Count" to count how many "P 15001" are there so the "Const NumRows& =" that number of row.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will copy all data **values** from the target workbook to current workbook, sheet-separated by "accounts" in target workbook column A.

```
Sub getdata()
    Dim rows As Integer
    Dim cols As Integer
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim crow As Integer
    Dim acc As String

    DoEvents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="demo.xls"
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "File does not exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    rows = Workbooks("demo.xls").Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).row
    cols = Workbooks("demo.xls").Sheets(1).Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
    For row = 1 To rows
        acc = Workbooks("demo.xls").Sheets(1).Cells(row, 1).Value
        If acc <> "" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(acc).Activate
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add().Name = acc
            End If
            crow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(acc).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).row + 1
            For col = 2 To cols
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(acc).Cells(crow, col - 1).Value = Workbooks("demo.xls").Sheets(1).Cells(row, col).Value
            Next
        End If
    Next
    'optional:
    'ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="YYYYMMDD.xls"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Downsides:

- Original sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3) will be preserved ---- I
  tried to delete them, but the code seems to cause trouble;
- There will be one empty row on every "account" sheet.

Comment: Passerby you my friend are a genius!!!!!!, Its beautiful!! The only, can you make to include the Column with the account Number which is column A, and Have the data post in row 6. This is just great. I have been breaking my head with this.

Comment: Oasserby I figure it out. I tweak it here and there. Thanks once again.

Comment: @cemg Really glad that I can help. I myself have to deal with Excel VBA from time to time.

Comment: @cemg BTW, if you find my post helpful, could you accept it as an answer?

Comment: Passerby, is there a way to have a the macro refresh the data. lets say I delete a block of cells, and then bring it back again by clicking with the macro you wrote.

Comment: @cemg I don't know about your modification, but in my code, it will always append data to corresponding sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all maybe not the best idea, just have to solve similar task, in my case its over 1000000 rows and about 56 sheets so copy all take time.

That i do I use same method to read values as in you example but have validation rule, so idea is to check that you read and if its that you need - save to string array, if not skip it - best result is then table is sorted by validation attribute. Sub code:

```
...
i = 2 'skiping hedears
flag = True 'flag to know then we need jump out of cicle
ScrMode = Application.ScreenUpdating 'save curent status
DoEvents 'allow others subs to do stuff
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Do While flag
    Address = Cells(i, ColNumber).Address 'there is colnumber where is validation value is stored, i - row count 
    strRetVal = GetData(DataFileName, SheetName, Address) 'get result
    If strRetVal <> "0" Then 'check if cell is empty (to know that its end of data column) in you case additional check required if returned result is = "P 15001"
        If strValString = "" Then
            strValString = strRetVal
        Else
            strValString = strValString & "," & strRetVal 'I am adding value there to long string, you may need to use few of them to collect all values you need, so one string variable per column
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Else
        flag = False
    End If
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = ScrMode 'restoring mode 
...
```

after this you will got bunch of strings with needed data that is related to validation string. Then you can save it to array like: strValArray = Split(strValString, ",") and past it to sheet if needed.